# Delete query in Mysql working wrong

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-delete

I have a SP:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test_ind(in StudentID varchar(4), in issueYear varchar(4))
BEGIN 
delete from Mark where StudentID = StudentID and issueYear = issueYear;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I call this SP: `call test_ind('8','2011')`

It must delete the studentID = 8 but it deleted all rows in table.

what wrong with this query?
Could you help me please!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a name collision that is happening on the stored procedure because the name of the parameter is exactly the same with the name of your columns.

Change the parameter name and it will work,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test_ind(IN _StudentID VARCHAR(4), IN _issueYear VARCHAR(4))
BEGIN 
    DELETE FROM Mark 
    WHERE  StudentID = _StudentID AND 
           issueYear = _issueYear;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: how can I close this question? I'm new here. Thank you very much!

Comment: You can mark the question as accepted by clicking the checkmark (*which turns into green*) on the left side of the question or just delete this if you feel that only you can benefit this question `:)`

Comment: I just want to mark this question as answered or something like that, not delete. Thank you again :)